# Flink ML - SVM Learning Runtime is way below expectations

Tags: machine-learning, svm, apache-flink, libsvm, supervised-learning

My goal is to evaluate the learning runtime of the SVMs from apache flink and apache spark.
Times ago this was already done in this article https://link.springer.com/article/10.1186/s41044-016-0020-2#Sec12 .

they are using datasets containing 6.5 million till 65 million instances with 631 features.

The first result shows the runtime of apache flink with the 6.5 million instances dataset.
Flink needs there 111 seconds to complete the learning (step size of 0.01 and a regularization parameter of 0.01).

In my following code snippet i am trying to rebuild this test, but it only takes 14 seconds, which sounds a bit unrealistic compared to the article.

```scala
object ScalabilityTest extends App {

    val env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

    val pathToTrainingFile = "hdfs:///datasets/vectorized-data-7-mio"

    val input: DataSet[LabeledVector] = env.readLibSVM(pathToTrainingFile)

    val model = SVM()
            .setBlocks(env.getParallelism)
            .setIterations(100)
            .setRegularization(0.01)
            .setStepsize(0.01)
            .setOutputDecisionFunction(true)

    model.fit(input)

    input.output(new DiscardingOutputFormat[LabeledVector])

    env.execute("flink svm scalability")
}
```

The dataset looks like:

```
0 2:0.0956973405770521 3:0.04302176671363839 63:0.22238596493564314 70:0.10967685914251926 139:0.23401113066755871 252:0.2197483438988253 555:0.4133093410994923 566:0.38936213517756474 1078:0.4758559946101788 1732:0.5005412038471097 3640:0.5518088141146315 5017:0.7249851063151311 7793:0.5518088141146315 
0 2:0.08886181625011981 3:0.039948783376949924 5:0.08410395321456549 82:0.18319049693258793 90:0.1919885302924892 256:0.21925479670962622 303:0.4053787361547381 325:0.22255697201807345 353:0.27518945356563856 530:0.31997134952306455 562:0.43392159248729284 785:0.49570712373633596 9066:0.6077511178730391 15357:0.7227109687611892 
0 1:0.10076144986545423 2:0.0691147459723154 3:0.06214255191969988 7:0.18335119128172658 20:0.08097367795302803 35:0.25318177398006236 37:0.04713864367763213 70:0.0792110649362639 111:0.17495017690637232 137:0.2826397578480119 153:0.17929691347274906 160:0.34589629247477904 256:0.1705315085519315 1091:0.26748048081097636 1281:0.28156097530039514 4054:0.36002041127390355
```

containing 7mio rows with 26k features.

question:

do i miss something here or how can it be, that my learning runtime with a dataset containing more rows and features is so much faster?

Comment: Which flink version are you using? What is your cluster like? I wouldn't be surprised to see it being legit; the paper is ancient compared to the life of Flink.

Comment: @ArvidHeise thanks for replying :) 

Using Flink version 1.9.1
Cluster contains 1 master and 3 slaves.
All machines have 32gb RAM and 8 cores (quadcore with hyper-threading) and 2 TB memory.

But also my values of the spark learning rate is way lower than the values of this paper.

So the code in general looks legit right?

Comment: Yes, both Spark and Flink significantly improved in the last 3 years. Especially the constanst startup time were heavily reduced. However, the paper also mentioned quite beefy machines. To be on the safe side, I'd try to evaluate a) also with the dataset in the paper and b) have a qualitative evaluation of the result. Since the training times are quite small, I'm positive that you could compare the RMSE of your models on the whole dataset with some non-distributed implementation in Python.

Comment: @ArvidHeise thanks for your help. i really appreciate it.
I also wanted to compare the LinearSVC from SparkML with the SVM models from Spark MLlib and FlinkML. I am not a machine learning expert, so maybe this is quite a stupid question to ask but: To have the same configurations i am setting the step size, regularization and the iterations. But i cant find any step size to set for the LinearSVC. how am i be able to compare the learning runtime? thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used SparkML yet. I guess, creating a new topic for that question is appropriate.